# I do not receive iOS push notifications from Element Matrix Notify

Tags: matrix, notifications, element, send

I integrated pytest into my pipeline, and when the pipeline runs and a test fails, a notification is sent to my Element room via Matrix Notify.

I receive the message in the app (Desktop, Web, App), but my iOS (iPhone) does not push a notification.

I would like to mention that I have received notifications from rooms like the Element iOS room.

I have checked the usual aspects, including the notification settings on iOS and Element. What else could it be?